# What is the Probability of being chosen in Proof of Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, staking, validators

I'm trying to solidify my understanding of Proof-Of-Stake consensus, and one thing I've been left wondering is how to figure the probability of being chosen to be a validator. Are the chances of being selected based on the amount of currency *in circulation*, or the amount of currency *being staked on the network*?

As a follow up (if it applies); in a PoS system that has a probability of being chosen only based on the total network amount being staked, wouldn't that mean a theoretical "51%" attack wouldn't have to own 51% of the market cap per-se, but actually only 51% of the "total stake"? In this scenario it seems like an attack like this would be much easier to carry out if the network isn't being widely staked with a moderate percentage of the total circulation.